# I am searching for a song from Little Big Planet 2. Can you help identify it?

Tags: game-music-identification, little-big-planet-2

Last time I played this game with some friend and there was one song I am frantically searching now...

Actually I don't really remember this song anymore. I just know that it's from first world (the world before the cake-world) and it was playing in a level after the level with Beethoven song.

Does anybody know a sorted soundtrack list of little big planet 2, sorted by worlds so I can easily find it?

Answer (score 12):

Here's [a site](http://www.littlebigland.com/the-music-of-lbp-2/) that has links to every song featured in the game. It's not sorted by world, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Nice find, finally found the song from the trailer!